# Parsing a file with BodyParser in Scala Play20 with new lines

Tags: parsing, scala, buffer, playframework-2.0

Excuse the n00bness of this question, but I have a web application where I want to send a potentially large file to the server and have it parse the format.  I'm using the Play20 framework and I'm new to Scala.

For example, if I have a csv, I'd like to split each row by "," and ultimately create a `List[List[String]]` with each field.

Currently, I'm thinking the best way to do this is with a BodyParser (but I could be wrong).    My code looks something like:

```
Iteratee.fold[String, List[List[String]]]() {
  (result, chunk) =>
    result = chunk.splitByNewLine.splitByDelimiter // Psuedocode
}
```

My first question is, how do I deal with a situation like the one below where a chunk has been split in the middle of a line:

```
Chunk 1:
1,2,3,4\n
5,6

Chunk 2:
7,8\n
9,10,11,12\n
```

My second question is, is writing my own BodyParser the right way to go about this?  Are there better ways of parsing this file?  My main concern is that I want to allow the files to be very large so I can flush a buffer at some point and not keep the entire file in memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your csv doesn't contain escaped newlines then it is pretty easy to do a progressive parsing without putting the whole file into memory. The iteratee library comes with a method search inside [`play.api.libs.iteratee.Parsing`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Parsing$) :

```
def search (needle: Array[Byte]): Enumeratee[Array[Byte], MatchInfo[Array[Byte]]]
```

which will partition your stream into `Matched[Array[Byte]]` and `Unmatched[Array[Byte]]`

Then you can combine a first iteratee that takes a header and another that will fold into the umatched results. This should look like the following code:

```
// break at each match and concat unmatches and drop the last received element (the match)
val concatLine: Iteratee[Parsing.MatchInfo[Array[Byte]],String] = 
  ( Enumeratee.breakE[Parsing.MatchInfo[Array[Byte]]](_.isMatch) ><>
    Enumeratee.collect{ case Parsing.Unmatched(bytes) => new String(bytes)} &>>
    Iteratee.consume() ).flatMap(r => Iteratee.head.map(_ => r))

// group chunks using the above iteratee and do simple csv parsing
val csvParser: Iteratee[Array[Byte], List[List[String]]] =
  Parsing.search("\n".getBytes) ><>
  Enumeratee.grouped( concatLine ) ><>
  Enumeratee.map(_.split(',').toList) &>>
  Iteratee.head.flatMap( header => Iteratee.getChunks.map(header.toList ++ _) )

// an example of a chunked simple csv file
val chunkedCsv: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator("""a,b,c
""","1,2,3","""
4,5,6
7,8,""","""9
""") &> Enumeratee.map(_.getBytes)

// get the result
val csvPromise: Promise[List[List[String]]] = chunkedCsv |>>> csvParser

// eventually returns List(List(a, b, c),List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
```

Of course you can improve the parsing. If you do, I would appreciate if you share it with the community.

So your Play2 controller would be something like:

```
val requestCsvBodyParser = BodyParser(rh => csvParser.map(Right(_)))

// progressively parse the big uploaded csv like file
def postCsv = Action(requestCsvBodyParser){ rq: Request[List[List[String]]] => 
  //do something with data
}
```

Comment: This code looks promising but it's going to take me a bit to understand...all the operators Scala has gives it a big learning curve.

Comment: Absolutely not, you can rewrite the previous code replacing ><> with compose, &>> by transform, |>>> by run. These operators are not from scala but are methods of the corresponding objects.

Comment: Ah yes, I read through the docs on Enumeratees again and this makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to pass an Enumerator of Strings into the Action? So that one could do something with the elements and then output the chunks using `Result.Ok.chunked()` for example.

As far as I can see here the body parser consumes the whole file into a `List[List[String]]` structure in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind holding twice the size of `List[List[String]]` in memory then you could use a body parser like `play.api.mvc.BodyParsers.parse.tolerantText`:

```
def toCsv = Action(parse.tolerantText) { request =>
  val data = request.body
  val reader = new java.io.StringReader(data)
  // use a Java CSV parsing library like http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/
  // to transform the text into CSV data
  Ok("Done")
}
```

Note that if you want to reduce memory consumption, I recommend using `Array[Array[String]]` or `Vector[Vector[String]]` depending on if you want to deal with mutable or immutable data.

If you are dealing with truly large amount of data (or lost of requests of medium size data) and your processing can be done incrementally, then you can look at rolling your own body parser. That body parser would not generate a `List[List[String]]` but instead parse the lines as they come and fold each line into the incremental result. But this is quite a bit more complex to do, in particular if your CSV is using double quote to support fields with commas, newlines or double quotes.