# How to convert Play! 2.0 Scala file into a format for CSVReader?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm having some issues getting file uploads to work correctly and the following code does not compile.

**The error**: `overloaded method constructor File with alternatives: (java.net.URI)java.io.File <and> (java.lang.String)java.io.File cannot be applied to (play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData.FilePart[play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile])`

**The code**:

```
def csvimport = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
      request.body.file("files[]").map { rawfile =>

        val filename = rawfile.filename 
        val contentType = rawfile.contentType
        val tmpFile = new File(rawfile)

        val reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(tmpFile))

        Ok
      }
      .getOrElse {
        Logger.debug(request.body.toString)
        BadRequest
      }
    }
```

Do I need to temporarily store the file to disk before I run a CSVReader on it? Is there not a way to convert a raw file upload to a new `File` class in memory?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to write your own body parser, as described here: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaFileUpload  (just commenting as I don't have any example code for you).

Comment: @WesFreeman damn was hoping to avoid it ;) thanks i'll post it up once i have it written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is I guess what you are trying to achieve

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11059295/317452

https://gist.github.com/2939230

This parses progressively chunks of the file without putting the whole raw file in memory or on disk.

Comment: Hmmm... certainly a good example, but if I wasn't clear my apologies since `CSVReader` is actually a class ref to the Java OpenCSV library ;) It's quite possible i'm having trouble with this because perhaps OpenCSV only supports a file. :O

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem:

Try:

```
request.body.file("Image").ref.file // Java.io.File
```

request.body is play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData

request.body.file("Image").ref is play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/Files$$TemporaryFile.html

Comment: not working, ref is not visible , so used getref() but once I do that, file isn't there associated with it